# How to add external resource/font into Firefox extension?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to add font into Firefox extension.

I've managed to add style with PageMode:

```
pageMod.PageMod({ ...
...
contentStyleFile: [
...
self.data.url('font-awesome.min.css')
],
```

inside the css I have:

```
font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('resource://extension_id/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3')
```

where extension_id is of course my ID.

when script loads I get:

downloadable font: download not allowed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: resource://extension_id/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3 font-awesome.min.css

Comment: I know my answer doesn't exactly correspond, given that you're using an absolute URL, but the solution should work nevertheless. Let me know if it does.

Answer (score 1):

See docs: [PageMod > Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) > ContentStyleFile

---

You can't currently use relative URLs in stylesheets loaded in this way. For example, consider a CSS file that references an external file like this:

```
background: rgb(249, 249, 249) url('../../img/my-background.png') repeat-x top center;
```

If you attach this file using contentStyleFile, "my-background.png" will not be found.

As a workaround for this, you can build an absolute URL to a file in your "data" directory, and construct a contentStyle option embedding that URL in your rule. For example:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentStyleFile: data.url("my-style.css"),
  // contentStyle is built dynamically here to include an absolute URL
  // for the file referenced by this CSS rule.
  // This workaround is needed because we can't use relative URLs
  // in contentStyleFile or contentStyle.
  contentStyle: "h1 { background: url(" + data.url("my-pic.jpg") + ")}"
});
```

This add-on uses a separate file "my-style.css", loaded using contentStyleFile, for all CSS rules except those that reference an external file. For the rule that needs to refer to "my-pic.jpg", which is stored in the add-on's "data" directory, it uses contentStyle.

Comment: this is not valid since a while. The documentation needs to be updated, thanks to point it out!

Comment: I knew there were a few bugs being worked on in regards to this, but didn't realize it had been solved. Thanks for the update.

Comment: It didn't work. I end up encoding fonts wit base64 instead.

Answer (score -1):

The CSS's assets are relative to the CSS loaded. So you do not need to use absolute path, but just relative path.