# How to use @font-face on a Firefox WebExtension

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to port a Chrome extension Firefox add-on using the [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) . 
In chrome extension I am using

```
src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/css/fonts/webFonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
```

to include fonts. What should I use in Firefox WebExtension?

Since I can't use browser.extension.getURL() in a CSS file, how can I use @font-face with a local font file?

Comment: Isnt it possible to use relative urls? Just skip the chrome-extension://id part?

Comment: @DanielHerr no its not working. I am injecting fonts in content script,by using relative path it will use current url's path

Comment: Try this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357596/firefox-extension-custom-fonts). An answer seems to have been provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use "moz-extension://..."

```
src: url('moz-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/css/fonts/webFonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a data uri with this: http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php then your css would look like `src:("data:application/font-woff;base64,.....") format("woff");`

I do this here -

https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/32d3bd62bb217b9d5a72fea29d41a426b158bdac/resources/styles/editor.css#L651